# Usage of the expression “He is no longer your uncle.”

Tags: idioms

I was watching last night the third episode of the first season of Endeavour, a British detective series set in the 1960's, when I came across the idiom “He is no longer your uncle,” when someone was talking about a dead man. 
As I have not seen this anywhere, I am asking if this is common usage among native speakers at all.

Comment: Surely this is either saying 'He's dead – you have to let him go' or 'He isn't your uncle, we've now proved, and you must not regard him as such any longer'.

Comment: This is not an idiom; it must have a literal meaning in the context. I am inclined to agree with Edwin, but we can't be sure without seeing the show.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=WitiDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%22no+longer+your+uncle%22&source=bl&ots=kViPHz9GoG&sig=kOIU3EDnqslljPLed__2fSsaaaY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif0NC-4_jbAhXK5IMKHYBiAgMQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%22no%20longer%20your%20uncle%22&f=false

Comment: *[Come into contact with a section of split electrical cable and Bob - or in this case, Lenny - is no longer your uncle.](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=endeavour-2013&episode=s01e03)*

Comment: The speaker is explaining how, Lenny, died and consequently is now **no longer** (a living) uncle.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yeah, there could be a link to the "Bob's your uncle" idiom.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about interpreting a phrase within the context of a drama. There may be all sorts of things going on that we can just not be aware of that would inform the meaning of the statement. Was the dead person the uncle of the person being spoken to?

Comment: @HotLicks Ah!, now is rather clear!, there is indeed a link. I had never heard of this before, so I thought it would not be an ordinary thing to say - very well, and thank you, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a relation to "Bob's your uncle", which is [reportedly](http://www.word-detective.com/back-f.html) derived from this incident:

> "Bob's your uncle" is a way of saying "you're all set" or "you've got
>   it made." It's a catch phrase dating back to 1887, when British Prime
>   Minister Robert Cecil (a.k.a. Lord Salisbury) decided to appoint a
>   certain Arthur Balfour to the prestigious and sensitive post of Chief
>   Secretary for Ireland. Not lost on the British public was the fact
>   that Lord Salisbury just happened to be better known to Arthur Balfour
>   as "Uncle Bob." In the resulting furor over what was seen as an act of
>   blatant nepotism, "Bob's your uncle" became a popular sarcastic
>   comment applied to any situation where the outcome was preordained by
>   favoritism. As the scandal faded in public memory, the phrase lost its
>   edge and became just a synonym for "no problem."

Presumably when a man is dead he can no longer function as your "uncle" and do things to your benefit.

Comment: But if you don't cite the precise quote your answer is less convincing

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Which "precise quote"?

Comment: This one *"What have we got? Doctor?// Electrocuted.
Rain's come in through the roof over a length of time.//
Puddled.//Come into contact with a section of split electrical cable* **and Bob** - or in this case, Lenny - **is** no longer **your uncle**".

Comment: Rather than 'no problem', I understand 'Bob's your uncle' to mean 'and so the desired result is achieved' after explaining a procedure.. In the bit of dialogue quoted by Mari-Lou, the doctor is explaining how an electrocution came to happen. With professional black humour, he twists the phrase to refer to the man being dead.

Answer (score 0):

**[No longer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20longer)** is an idiom almost synonymous with **'[no more](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%20more)'**. So, it is idiomatic to use 'no longer' to talk about a 'dead person'.

> ***No longer*** is used to say that something that was once true or possible is not now true or possible.
>
> ***No More*** is used to mean (sense 2 of MW dictionary)  *no longer in existence : dead, departed*.

Comment: Perfectly right.

Comment: But this wasn't the question.